# jquery ui datepicker setDate method calendar at bottom of the page

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating to latest JQuery UI and datepicker is causing the datepicker to always be seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735888/updating-to-latest-jquery-ui-and-datepicker-is-causing-the-datepicker-to-always)

This is what my code looks like in JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2012,7,23), maxDate: new Date(2012,11,14)});
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

except that when I load it, the datepicker calendar automatically shows up at the bottom of the page. I tried the solution from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jquery-ui/805gSvQOy5c) but it doesn't work. I also have the datepicker inside an accordion. Would that be part of the problem? Please let me know of any solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have found the solution in this question [Updating to latest JQuery UI and datepicker is causing the datepicker to always be seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735888/updating-to-latest-jquery-ui-and-datepicker-is-causing-the-datepicker-to-always):

```
$(function() { 
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2012,7,23), maxDate: new Date(2012,11,14)});
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('display','none');  
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date()); 
});
```