# jQuery datepicker getting displayed at the bottom of the page (Keith-Wood datepicker)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I had an issue with jquery datepicker(Keith-Wood)(http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html). It worked fine on jquery 1.6.4 but after I migrated to jQuery 1.10.2 the widget appeared at the bottom of the page on every instances in which the date picker was used.

The functionality works fine, just the position got messed up.

[image: widget opening at the bottom]

I need to have widget open write below the DateAdded section. If I switch back to jQuery 1.6.4 the positioning is correct. Here is the screen shot while using jQuery 1.6.4

[image]

Below is the function that I use to trigger the calendar.

```
function open_calendar()
{
    jQuery('.open_calendar').datepick(
    {
       beforeShow: function(input, inst)
       {
          inst.dpDiv.css({marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px'});
       },
       dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
       rangeSelect: false,
       monthsToShow: [1,2],
       monthsOffset: 0,
       monthsToStep: 1,
       //supress the inline css used by jquery for div width
onShow:function(){
        jQuery('.datepick-multi').css({'width':'426'});
        jQuery('.datepick-popup').css({'z-index':'20000'});
        },
        constrainInput:false,
        showOnFocus:false,
        showTrigger:"<button type='button' title='Pick Date' style='padding:1px;' name='StartDatePicker' id='StartDatePicker'><img src='/images/calendarpicker.gif' alt='Pick Date' width='16' height='13'></button>"
        });
}
```

I need to have the position of the widget to stack right below the textbox from which it is triggered.

Comment: You might need to add `position: relative;` to your `date added` wrapping container.

Comment: nope, did not work :(

Comment: the demo page you showed is using 'jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js' so it doesn't look like its the jquery. Did you try updating the plugin js?

Comment: yup I updated the plugin and the images above displays the use of both version of the jQuery as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you updated jquery did you also update jquery.plugin.js, jquery.datepick.js, and jquery.datepick.css from http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html? I think older versions of the datepick plugin are likely not compatible with newer versions of jQuery, but if you update the datepick plugin it should work. Check it out, it works with version 5.0 of datepick plugin and version 1.10.2 of jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/t3kLr8d4/3/

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.datepick.css" id="theme">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="date" />
```

**CSS**

```
/* Default styling for jQuery Datepicker v5.0.0. */
.datepick {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.25em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.25em;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.datepick-rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
.datepick-popup {
    z-index: 1000;
}
.datepick-disable {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.datepick a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.datepick a.datepick-disabled {
    color: #888;
    cursor: auto;
}
.datepick button {
    margin: 0.25em;
    padding: 0.125em 0em;
    background-color: #fcc;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.25em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.25em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.datepick-nav, .datepick-ctrl {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.datepick-ctrl {
    background-color: #600;
}
.datepick-cmd {
    width: 30%;
}
.datepick-cmd:hover {
    background-color: #777;
}
.datepick-ctrl .datepick-cmd:hover {
    background-color: #f08080;
}
.datepick-cmd-prevJump, .datepick-cmd-nextJump {
    width: 8%;
}
a.datepick-cmd {
    height: 1.5em;
}
button.datepick-cmd {
    text-align: center;
}
.datepick-cmd-prev, .datepick-cmd-prevJump, .datepick-cmd-clear {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2%;
}
.datepick-cmd-current, .datepick-cmd-today {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    text-align: center;
}
.datepick-cmd-next, .datepick-cmd-nextJump, .datepick-cmd-close {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 2%;
    text-align: right;
}
.datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-prev, .datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-prevJump,
.datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-clear {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 0%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    text-align: right;
}
.datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-current, .datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-today {
    float: right;
}
.datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-next, .datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-nextJump,
.datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-close {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    text-align: left;
}
.datepick-month-nav {
    float: left;
    background-color: #777;
    text-align: center;
}
.datepick-month-nav div {
    float: left;
    width: 12.5%;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
}
.datepick-month-nav span {
    color: #888;
}
.datepick-month-row {
    clear: left;
}
.datepick-month {
    float: left;
    width: 15em;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    text-align: center;
}
.datepick-month-header, .datepick-month-header select, .datepick-month-header input {
    height: 1.5em;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.datepick-month-header select, .datepick-month-header input {
    height: 1.4em;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    border: none;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.datepick-month-header input {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.datepick-month table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.datepick-month thead {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.datepick-month th, .datepick-month td {
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
.datepick-month th {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
.datepick-month th, .datepick-month th a {
    background-color: #777;
    color: #fff;
}
.datepick-month td {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.datepick-month td.datepick-week {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
.datepick-month td.datepick-week * {
    background-color: #777;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
}
.datepick-month a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.125em 0em;
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.datepick-month span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.125em 0em;
}
.datepick-month td span {
    color: #888;
}
.datepick-month td .datepick-other-month {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.datepick-month td .datepick-weekend {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.datepick-month td .datepick-today {
    background-color: #f0c0c0;
}
.datepick-month td .datepick-highlight {
    background-color: #f08080;
}
.datepick-month td .datepick-selected {
    background-color: #777;
    color: #fff;
}
.datepick-month th.datepick-week {
    background-color: #777;
    color: #fff;
}
.datepick-status {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #ddd;
    text-align: center;
}
.datepick-clear-fix {
    clear: both;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#date').datepick({
       beforeShow: function(input, inst)
       {
          inst.dpDiv.css({marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px'});
       },
       dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
       rangeSelect: false,
       monthsToShow: [1,2],
       monthsOffset: 0,
       monthsToStep: 1,
       //supress the inline css used by jquery for div width
onShow:function(){
        jQuery('.datepick-multi').css({'width':'426'});
        jQuery('.datepick-popup').css({'z-index':'20000'});
        },
        constrainInput:false,
        showOnFocus:false,
        showTrigger:"<button type='button' title='Pick Date' style='padding:1px;' name='StartDatePicker' id='StartDatePicker'><img src='/images/calendarpicker.gif' alt='Pick Date' width='16' height='13'></button>"
});
```

Comment: Turns out I had not updated my jquery ui files and they were still active in the dependency files and it was overwriting the new updates. Thanks for pointing me out in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case people run into similar problem like mine here is a solution that I used,

```
function open_calendar()
{
$('.open_calendar').datepick({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst)
    {
        inst.dpDiv.css({marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth + 'px'});
    },
dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    rangeSelect: false,
    monthsToShow: [1,2],
    monthsOffset: 0,
    monthsToStep: 1,
    //supress the inline css used by jquery for div width
    onShow:function(){
        //this will retrieve the postion of the element that triggers your calendar
        var position=jQuery(this).position();
        jQuery('.datepick-multi').css({'width':'426'});
        //I added the 25px to the position to show the calendar just below the text box
        jQuery('.datepick-popup').css({'z-index':'20000','top':position.top+25});
    },
    constrainInput:false,
    showOnFocus:false,
    showTrigger:"<button type='button' title='Pick Date' style='padding:1px;' name='StartDatePicker' id='StartDatePicker'><img src='/images/calendarpicker.gif' alt='Pick Date' width='16' height='13'></button>"
    });
}
```

The reason I added 25px is because all the textbox on my site are adjusted to that height, you can modify it as per your use.

> Note: jQuery does not support getting the position coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element. For more info, view this[jQuery Position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

Answer (score 0):

For someone who would get frustrated using keith wood's datepicker in higher versions of jquery. (I used jquery 3.3.1). 
Here is what i did.

**CSS :**

```
.calendars-popup {
    position: absolute;
    top: unset !important;
    left: unset !important;
    right: 15px;
}
```

The css is sufficient to cover for all browsers, except IE (11,10,9). 
For IE,  Make below changes.

**jquery.calendars.picker.js :**

1) Replace `andSelf` with `addBack`

2) _showPlugin method: comment this line

```
inst.div.css({left: offset.left, top: offset.top});
```

3) _update  method : comment these lines

```
left: target.offset().left,
top: target.offset().top + target.outerHeight()
```

These lines cause an inline css of top & left which makes IE positioning haywire.

This might not be the best way but it solved for me.

**BTW**: I also used their arabic picker along with this.